# Hide table row based on a CSS property of a cell's content

Tags: javascript

I have a table and one cell per row has content whose CSS display switches between none and visible (based on a separate Wordpress wishlist plugin). When it's set to none, I want the whole row to also set to display:none. How can I do this with javascript?

Comment: Post your code in your question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your html is something like this:

```
<table>
<tr><td>foo</td><td>bar</td></tr>
<tr><td style="display:none">foo</td><td>bar</td></tr>
<tr><td>foo</td><td>bar</td></tr>
</table>
```

And you want the second row to also have the style `display:none` (or at least this is what I am understanding from your question), then your jquery code should be something like this:

```
$('td').filter(function () { return $(this).css('display') == 'none' }).parent().css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: Answering based on  assumptions it isn't always a good thing to do.

Comment: That's exactly it! Thanks so much!